# UITapGestureRecognizer swallows all gestures

Tags: ios, uiview, uiviewcontroller, multi-touch, uitapgesturerecognizer

I'm trying to add a UITapGestureRecognizer to my app so I can detect and act upon all two finger taps, but pass any other user input through. Sounds trivial, but I just can't get it to work. Here's my code so far, inside my main view controller:

```
- (void) viewDidLoad {
  // other init stuff
  UITapGestureRecognizer *tapRecognizer = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(handleTap:)];
  [tapRecognizer setNumberOfTouchesRequired:2];
  [tapRecognizer setNumberOfTapsRequired:1];
  [tapRecognizer setCancelsTouchesInView:NO];

  UIView *tapHolderView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, self.view.frame.size.width, self.view.frame.size.height)];
  [tapHolderView setMultipleTouchEnabled:YES];
  [tapHolderView addGestureRecognizer:tapRecognizer];

  [self.view addSubview:tapHolderView];

  [tapRecognizer release];
}

- (void) handleTap:(UITapGestureRecognizer *) sender {
  if (sender.state == UIGestureRecognizerStateEnded) {
    // do something
  }
}
```

What happens is this: A two finger tap will trigger the handleTap method. Any other user input, be it swipe, pinch, single-finger-tap and so on, will not be picked up by any other view (a UIToolbar, a UIWebView amongst others).

I'd very much appreciate any insight at all on this, and please let me know if I haven't been specific enough about the problem.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try setting the view controller to be a delegate of UIGestureRecognizerDelegate, and implement gestureRecognizer:shouldRecognizeSimulaneouslyWithGestureRecgonizer to always return 'YES'.  Example:

```
- (BOOL)gestureRecognizer:(UIGestureRecognizer *)gestureRecognizer shouldRecognizeSimultaneouslyWithGestureRecognizer:(UIGestureRecognizer *)otherGestureRecognizer
{
    return YES;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for helping out. I what you suggest, still same result. I also added a log statement in the shouldRecognizeSimultaneouslyWithGestureRecognizer method, and it seems to never get called. Maybe this is a clue to solving my problem?

Comment: AH! I didn't need the shouldRecognizeSimultaneouslyWithGestureRecognizer but, I added a UITapGestureRecognizer to my view, not to a new view which I added as a subview, then touches get passed as expected! Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

The only thing I can think of is the use of:

```
 [tapRecognizer setDelegate:self];
```

have you defined any delegate methods for your gesture recognizer in your view controller? would you try commenting that line out for a quick test?

Comment: Thanks for trying to help! If I comment out that line, the handleTap method isn't called, and no gestures are detected at all in any view.

Comment: interesting... setting a delegate is not required for the gesture recognizer to work. have you defined any delegate methods? is there any other gesture recognizer that might affect the first one?

Comment: Oh, sorry, my bad. When I comment out [tapRecognizer setDelegate:self] I get the same result: handleTap is called on two-finger-tap, but no other gestures are passed on to the other views. Updated the question with removing this line. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

We have implemented single tap and double tap gesture in same view. Hope this helps

```
UITapGestureRecognizer *singleTap = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] 
                                     initWithTarget:self 
                                     action:@selector(handleSingleTapOnMainImageView:)];

[self addGestureRecognizer:singleTap];
[singleTap release];

UITapGestureRecognizer *doubleTap = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] 
                                     initWithTarget:self 
                                     action:@selector(handleDoubleTapOnMainImageView:)];
[doubleTap setNumberOfTapsRequired:2];
[singleTap requireGestureRecognizerToFail:doubleTap];
[self addGestureRecognizer:doubleTap];
[doubleTap release];
```

Comment: Is this working code? You're accessing singleTap after it was released, right?

Comment: This is working code. **alloc** needs to be **released**. Yes I'm accessing singleTap after it was released. But before release I've added gesture on my View. have a good day...

Comment: It works because `self` has retained `singleTap`, so it wasn't deallocated. It's still very bad style and in a non-ARC world, both gesture recognizers should be released at the end of this block of code.